# Method of laptop conditional power management in Windows 11

Tags: laptop, battery, power-management

I would like to set conditional power management rules based on the level of the charge of the battery.

I currently have appropriate rules set for on-power and on-battery. In addition to this, I would like the on-power settings to apply if the battery charge level is over 75%. The purpose of this is to stop my aggressive sleep settings applying when the battery has a good charge. I have yet to come up with a method of doing this, but I have thought that maybe a python script could change the on-battery power settings based on the charge level. This would involve me installing python, and running a script as a service. I'm not sure, but I suspect the script may need administrator privileges.

Before I start investigating this idea, I was wondering if there was a better, simpler method of doing this, as the requirement does not seem complicated.

Is there a method of setting power settings in Windows systems based on the battery charge percentage?

Comment: If your laptop has the function it is tied to BIOS (UEFI) and 80% is considered to be the correct level. Look in your machine for Battery Threshold Manager.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have this option. The only option related to this I have is to stop charging at 80% for the sake of battery health..

Comment: I understand and I keep my  batteries at 80% but I have the Threshold function and you need it as well to keep batteries charged to just 80%. Otherwise, you need to charge to full and then unplug for some time and repeat. Ask manufacturer support if a BIOS (UEFI) upgrade will provide the function.

Comment: I am guessing what @John is attempting to convey is that conditionally charging your battery requires third-party software and specific support by the firmware of your device.  Windows does not have any feature to conditionally charge your battery based on a charge level.

Comment: Maybe I have misrepresented myself. I have it set that my PC does not sleep when plugged in (amongst other settings), but it goes to sleep in 5 minutes if on battery. I don't want the computer to go to sleep if it has a charge above a certain level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a python script to manage this. It requires only python, does not need admin rights, and no additional modules are required.

```
import subprocess
import time
import datetime

battery_watermark = 75
sleep_on_battery_mins = 20

def set_standby_timeout_dc(mins):
    return subprocess.call("powercfg -change -standby-timeout-dc " +str(mins))

def battery_precentage():
    return int(subprocess.run(["WMIC", "PATH", "Win32_Battery", "Get", "EstimatedChargeRemaining"], capture_output=True).stdout.decode().split("\n")[1][:3].strip())

def on_battery():
    #BatteryStatus returns 2 when connected to AC.
    charging_status = int(subprocess.run(["WMIC", "PATH", "Win32_Battery", "Get", "BatteryStatus"], capture_output=True).stdout.decode().split("\n")[1].strip())
    if charging_status == 2:
        return False
    else:
        return True

print("Windows Power settings changer")
starttime = time.time()
while True:
    if (battery_precentage() > battery_watermark) and on_battery():
            print(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ": Setting on-battery standby timeout to 0, battery at " + str(battery_precentage()) + "%, on battery: " + str(on_battery()))
            set_standby_timeout_dc(0)
    else:
        print(str(datetime.datetime.now()) + ": Setting on-battery standby timeout to " + str(sleep_on_battery_mins) + ", battery at " + str(battery_precentage()) + "%, on battery: " + str(on_battery()))
        set_standby_timeout_dc(sleep_on_battery_mins)
    time.sleep(((sleep_on_battery_mins/2)-1)*60 - ((time.time() - starttime) %60))
```